# When can I say that the function is independent of the variable x?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

What can I say about the function $\varphi$, if $\varphi\in L^p\left((a,b)\times (c,d)\right)$ and 
$$
\int_c^d \varphi(x,y) dy=0\mbox{ a.e. }x\in (a,b) ?
$$
Can I say that $\varphi$ is independent of $x$? If I can not, when will I be able to conclude that $\varphi$ independs on $x$?

Of course, what other properties this $\varphi$ can have?

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi (x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ with $\int_c^{d} g(y)dy=0$ then the hypothesis is satisfied but $\phi $ is not independent of $x$, even if $f$ and $g$, (hence $\phi $) are smooth. I have no idea why you thin k that $\phi $ should be independent of $x$.

Comment: For example $\varphi (x,y)=x(y-\frac {c+d}{2})$... BTW the limits on the integral in your Answer should be $ c,d,$  not $a,b$...........+1